# Sending email using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have wrote a stored Procedure that send nightly emails

```
   'Sent to: ' + @EmailAddress + ';  
            To Whom It May concern:<br><br> 
                    On '+ @StartDate +' an XXXX was at '+ @EventTitle +' and these issues were identified:<br>
                      '+ @IssuesIdentified +' and marked as requiring your assistance to follow up with the concern.<br><br>
              Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter.'
```

Now I wanted to add the department name to this email. The reason is that I have 23 departments that get this notification email.
9 to 23 of this departments use the same email address, but once this person gets the email he/she has to create a ticket to notify the right department to follow up.

here is my query for the email that is working right now

```
    DECLARE @email varchar(max);
 ; 
   With TS 
            as  ( select MAX(ID) as Id 
                from dimAgencyEmail d
                    group by id 
            ) 
        select @email = coalesce(@Email + ';', '') + EmailAddress
        from dimAgencyEmail d
             join TSC c on c.Id = d.Id

   select @email;
```

here is the requirement

```
    Select case FollowUpBy_DepartmentName 
           when 1
            then (select emailaddress from dimAgencyEmail
      where Id ='1' ) --- there are 23 Id  
       from TSC where Requires_O_FollowUp = 1 
    or Requires_O1_FollowUp = 1
               and NotificationSentDate is null
```

I need help writing the query

In my email I would like to put the department Name so the person who gets this email knows which department need to respond to the follow UP. 
what I'm having difficulty with is, the person who creates this form can choose as many of this followUps as he wants. when sending email If requiresofficer or requiresother follow up is 1 and Notifications email is null then I need to send an email that includes all the departments that is checked, I'm having a hard time writing the query that does this. I will try using a temp table but if I can I would like to avoid it.

```
Sent to: ' + @EmailAddress + ';  
            To Whom It May concern:<br><br> 
                On '+ @StartDate +' an XXXX was at '+ @EventTitle +' and these issues were identified:<br>
                     '+ @IssuesIdentified +' and marked as requiring your assistance to follow up with the concern.<br><br> For the 000 center please create a ticket for MO, '+ @DepartmentName". 
               Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter.'
```

any help to query the departmentName is appreciated.

Please don't flag my question, I'm new to this and I'm learning how to ask question properly. If you can't answer give someone a chance to take a look.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my full Stored procedure

Comment: Your database model please. And how your requirements fit in there.

Comment: there is my full SP.   follow up animalWelfare to Transit uses the same email address. once the email is sent to this person he/she has to create a ticket to the right department. I want to write a query that does that for the department and include it in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this might help.

```
    -- DECLARE @EmailDetail TABLE  (NO need for temp table)

--create ctblEmailDetail table and populate with these fields (FollowUpBy1/2,FollowUpByAutoTheft ...FollowUpByTransit )
-- And use this table to fetch the necessary followUps match up by joining it.
CREATE TABLE ctblEmailDetail
(
ID IDENTITY(1,1) TINYINT,
FollowUp_Desc VARCHAR(250)  
ACTIVE BIT ,CREATEBY VARCHAR(20), CREATEDATE DATETIME   
)

/*
--EXAMPLE
ID  FollowUp_Desc 
-------------------------   
1   FollowUpBy1  
2   FollowUpBy2  
3   FollowUp2  
4   FollowUpBySeniorAffairs  
5   FollowUpBySolidWaste  
...
n   FollowUpByTransit  
*/

 DECLARE 

 @ID  AS INT, 
 @DepartmentName varchar(255),
 @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(max), 
 @StartDate Date,
 @EventTitle varchar(255),
 @NotificationSentDate Datetime2(7),
 @RequiresOfficerFollowUp Bit,
 @RequiresOtherFollowUp Bit,
 @IssuesIdentified varchar(255), 
 @DepartmentName AS varchar(255),
 @EmailAddress AS nvarchar(max), 
 @StartDate AS Date,
 @EventTitle AS varchar(255),
 @NotificationSentDate AS Datetime2(7),

 ---fields
 @RequiresOfficerFollowUp AS varchar(255),
 @RequiresOtherFollowUp AS varchar(255),
 @IssuesIdentified AS varchar(255), 

 --email fields
@Body varchar(1000),
@Subject varchar(200)

SET @StartDate = convert(varchar,'2019-06-01 01:31:00.0000000',7) 
SET @Subject = 'Comunity event follow up needed<br>' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1);

SELECT EventTitle
        ,StartDate
        ,IssuesIdentified
        ,RequiresOfficerFollowUp
        ,RequiresOtherFollowUp
    --   CASE WHEN ED.ID = 1 THEN  FollowUpByHorseMountedUnit 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 2  THEN FollowUpByArmedRobbery 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 3  THEN FollowUpByBurglary 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 4  THEN FollowUpByAutoTheft 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 5  THEN FollowUpByNarcotics 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 6  THEN FollowUpByVice 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 7  THEN FollowUpByGangs 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 8  THEN FollowUpByMotorUnit 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 9  THEN FollowUpByAnimalWelfare 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 10 THEN FollowUpByAviation 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 11 THEN FollowUpByCityCouncil 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 12 THEN FollowUpByCivilianPoliceOversightAgency 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 13 THEN FollowUpByEnvironmentalHealthDepartment 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 14 THEN FollowUpByFamilyCommunityServicesDepartment 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 15 THEN FollowUpByFire 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 16 THEN FollowUpByLegal 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 17 THEN FollowUpByMayorOffice 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 18 THEN  FollowUpByMunicipalDevelopmentDepartment 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 19 THEN FollowUpByParksRecreationDepartment 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 20 THEN FollowUpByPlanningDepartment 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 21 THEN FollowUpBySeniorAffairs 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 22 THEN FollowUpBySolidWaste 
    --      WHEN ED.ID = 23 THEN FollowUpByTransit ELSE NULL END AS FollowUp_Desc 
      ,ED.FollowUp_Desc
      ,NotificationSentDate  
FROM [dbo].[TraCSCommunityEventSummary] tcsc -- Don't forget to create ID Column in 'TraCSCommunityEventSummary' table from the ctblEmailDetail table.
LEFT JOIN ctblEmailDetail WITH (NOLOCK) ED ON tcsc.ID = ED.ID
WHERE tcsc.RequiresOfficerFollowUp = '1'
     OR tcsc.RequiresOtherFollowUp = '1' 
     AND tcsc. NotificationSentDate IS NULL 


SELECT @EmailAddress = coalesce(@EmailAddress + ';', '') + EmailAddress
FROM [dimAgencyEmail] d
OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT MAX(ID) as Id 
        FROM [dimAgencyEmail] d
        GROUP BY ID 
    )  c on c.Id = d.Id

SELECT @EmailAddress;   

SELECT DISTINCT D.DepartmentName, d.EmailAddress 
FROM [dimAgencyEmail] d
WHERE (d.DepartmentName In ('Animal Welfare', 'Aviation Department','City Council',
                            'Civilian Police Oversite Agency','Enviromental Health Dept.',
                            'Family & Community Services Dept.','Fire','Legal Depaartment',
                            'Mayors Office','Municipal Development Dept.','Parks & Recration Dept.',
                            'Planning Dept.','Senior Affairs Dept.','Sold Waste Dept.','Transit Dept.')) ;

SELECT tcsc.EventTitle
        ,tcsc.StartDate
        ,tcsc.IssuesIdentified
        ,tcsc.RequiresOfficerFollowUp
        ,tcsc.RequiresOtherFollowUp 
        ,tcsc.NotificationSentDate 
        ,CED.FollowUp_Desc
FROM [dbo].[TraCSCommunityEventSummary] tcsc 
LEFT JOIN ctblEmailDetail CED ON tcsc.ID = CED.ID
WHERE tcsc.RequiresOfficerFollowUp = '1'
       OR tcsc.RequiresOtherFollowUp = '1' 
       AND tcsc. NotificationSentDate IS NULL

-- I didnt get time to look after this line ;)

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT EventTitle,StartDate,IssuesIdentified,RequiresOfficerFollowUp,RequiresOtherFollowUp, FollowUpByHorseMountedUnit, 
           FollowUpByArmedRobbery ,FollowUpByBurglary ,
           FollowUpByAutoTheft ,FollowUpByNarcotics ,FollowUpByVice ,FollowUpByGangs ,
           FollowUpByMotorUnit ,FollowUpByAnimalWelfare ,FollowUpByAviation ,
           FollowUpByCityCouncil ,FollowUpByCivilianPoliceOversightAgency ,
           FollowUpByEnvironmentalHealthDepartment ,FollowUpByFamilyCommunityServicesDepartment ,
           FollowUpByFire ,FollowUpByLegal ,FollowUpByMayorOffice , FollowUpByMunicipalDevelopmentDepartment ,
           FollowUpByParksRecreationDepartment ,FollowUpByPlanningDepartment ,FollowUpBySeniorAffairs ,
           FollowUpBySolidWaste ,FollowUpByTransit,NotificationSentDate  
   FROM  @EmailDetail 

OPEN c1 
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO  @EventTitle,@StartDate,@IssuesIdentified,@RequiresOfficerFollowUp,@RequiresOtherFollowUp, 
                         @FollowUpByHorseMountedUnit,@FollowUpByArmedRobbery, @FollowUpByBurglary ,
                         @FollowUpByAutoTheft ,@FollowUpByNarcotics ,@FollowUpByVice ,@FollowUpByGangs ,
                         @FollowUpByMotorUnit ,@FollowUpByAnimalWelfare ,@FollowUpByAviation ,
                         @FollowUpByCityCouncil ,@FollowUpByCivilianPoliceOversightAgency ,
                         @FollowUpByEnvironmentalHealthDepartment ,@FollowUpByFamilyCommunityServicesDepartment ,
                         @FollowUpByFire ,@FollowUpByLegal ,@FollowUpByMayorOffice , @FollowUpByMunicipalDevelopmentDepartment ,
                         @FollowUpByParksRecreationDepartment ,@FollowUpByPlanningDepartment ,@FollowUpBySeniorAffairs ,
                         @FollowUpBySolidWaste ,@FollowUpByTransit,@NotificationSentDate 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1 
BEGIN 
SET @Body =  'Sent to: ' + @EmailAddress + ';  
            To Whom It May concern:<br><br> 
                On '+ @StartDate +' an xxxx was at '+ @EventTitle +' and these issues were identified:<br>
                   '+ @IssuesIdentified +' and marked as requiring your assistance to follow up with the concern.<br>
                     For the xxx Center, please create a ticket for the xxxxx.<br>
                  '+ @DepartmentName +' there are items on this request that require follow up by their office.<br><br> 
           Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter.'

BEGIN
              EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @profile_name = 'xxx',
              @recipients = 'xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx', -- @EmailAddress,
              @from_address = 'noreply@xxxx.xxx', 
              @reply_to = 'noreply@xxxx.xxx',
              @subject = @subject,
              @body = @body,
              @body_format = 'HTML',
              @importance = 'High',
              @sensitivity = 'Confidential';
              END
       end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, the problem is that you were sending a static email to all departments and now you have a list of multiple departments that you need to send different emails to.

Assuming that is the case, put the non-static variables (email, department, and any others) into a temp table, then loop through them.  Something like this:

```
--DECLARE Variables
DECLARE @email varchar(255)
DECLARE @department varchar(255)
etc...

--Populate temp table with all email/dept combos 
--(guessing at some logic here)
SELECT FollowUpBy_DepartmentName Dept, EmailAddress Email
INTO #DeptEmails
FROM TSC t
JOIN dimAgencyEmail e ON t.ID = e.ID --?
WHERE Requires_O_FollowUp = 1 
OR Requires_O1_FollowUp = 1
AND NotificationSentDate is null --Make sure this OR logic is right..
```

Then:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #DeptEmails)
BEGIN
    SET @Department = (SELECT TOP 1 Dept FROM #DeptEmails)
    SET @Email = (SELECT email FROM #DeptEmails WHERE Dept = @Department)

    --Form email and send here
    --(Your email query + EXEC msdb.send_dbmail etc.)

    --Remove department/email record now that it has been sent
    DELETE FROM #DeptEmails WHERE Dept = @Department

--Loop will begin again until all department emails have been sent
END
```

Comment: I have posted the full SP I did. so what I'm having difficulty with is, the person who creates this form can choose as many of this followUps as he wants. when sending email If requiresofficer or requiresother follow up is 1 and Notifications email is null then I need to send an email that includes all the departments that is checked, I'm having a hard time writing the query that does this. I will try using a temp table but if I can I would like to avoid it.